# I do not understand why I am receiving "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector"

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

```
bool sizeCheck (int numFiles, vector <int> signalFileSizes, vector<int> backgroundFileSizes){ 
for (int i=0;i<numFiles;i++){
    if(signalFileSize[i] != backgroundFileSizes[i]){
     return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

I do not understand why I am receiving "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector" . Or more accurately, how do you get the items in a vector?

Comment: Also: `std::vector` has a `size()` method so there is no need to pass the number of files (and it is actually dangerous). do : `numFiles = std::min(signalFileSizes.size(), backgroundFileSizes.size()` or better yet start by checking that the two vectors are of the same size.

Comment: Even better, replace this with `signalFileSizes != backgroundFileSizes`. Unlike this, it will actually check each value in the two vectors instead of only the first value (having undefined behaviour if `numFiles <= 0`) and handle vectors of different sizes. It will also use the original vectors instead of doing unnecessary copies/moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's line up the variables in your function header and body:

```
              v
signalFileSizes
signalFileSize
              ^
```

Hmm, I wonder if that makes it any more obvious :-)